# fluentd / Ruby issue with arrays

Tags: ruby, fluentd

I have three different occurrences of an error field in JSON.

I would like to rename it if its value is a string, when it's not in an array (only in case A, see below).

```
require 'json'

A = '{
    "http" : {
        "body": {  
            "value1" : "hello",
            "error" : "blabla"
        }
    }
}'


B = '{
        "http": {
            "body": {
                "value1": "hello",
                "error": {
                    "message": "hellohello",
                    "path": "here it is"
                }
            }
        }
    }'
    
C = '{
    "http": {
        "body": [
            {
                "value1": "dsa",
                "value2": "sadsad",
                "firstname": "Danss",
                "error" : "hello2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The ruby script below works fine with all 3 cases (A,B,C)

```
parsed_json = JSON.parse(B)
body = parsed_json["http"]["body"]

if !body.is_a?(Array)
  body["error_string"] = body.delete("error") if body["error"].is_a?(String)
end
puts JSON.pretty_generate(parsed_json)
```

However when I try to put this logic into fluent.d's record transformer:

```
<filter logs.incoming>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    http ${body = record["http"]["body"]
          if !body.is_a?(Array)
            body["error_string"] = body.delete("error") if body["error"].is_a?(String)
          end
          record["http"]}
  </record>
</filter>
```

With the script above fluent.d does nothing in case of dataset A
What gives?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer), between `${}` you should put an expression, and I think in your example you're using three: the initial assignment, the `if` and the final `record`. I would try to encapsulate your logic in one single expression, if possible. For instance, you could try `http ${record["http"].tap do |http_record| if !body...` and so on. With `Object#tap` you're sticking to using a single complex expression (the `.tap` call)

Comment: @Pipetus: Also, in Ruby, you can turn anything into a single expression by enclosing it in parentheses. E.g. `(1; 2; 3)` is a single expression whose value is `3`.

Comment: Thanks @Pipetus after modifying the expression it worked.